# Constantly increasing response times with akka http client

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I'm using the akka http client (version 10.0.0) to make requests to an endpoint served by a PHP Yii framework based application. The following code is executed every time a request is to be made:

```
val importConfimMsg = new ImportConfirmMessage(msg.orderId, msg.shipmentDate)

val uri = Uri(config.getString("endpoint.url"))
  .withQuery(Query("call_id" -> config.getString("endpoint.call_id"),
    "cmd" -> config.getString("endpoint.cmd")
  ))

val request = HttpRequest(method = POST, uri = uri, entity = importConfimMsg)

val result = http.singleRequest(request)
  .map(r => r.entity.dataBytes.runWith(Sink.ignore))
```

The first few requests receive responses in a matter of milliseconds but as the application continues to run and send more requests I'm seeing response times rising steadily to several seconds, then to tens of seconds and eventually timing out at the one minute mark.

Is my implementation incorrect?

Comment: Did you measure how many requests you are making per second? Did you try sending requests to a different server? You can also run `Wireshark` to see what is being sent and received.

Comment: I did not include this in the example but that block of code is followed by an `Await.result(result, Long.MaxValue nanos)` so the requests are made synchronously on a single thread. I don't believe that I'm flooding the target server with too many requests. Even if that were the case, my understanding is that akka http should back pressure the outgoing requests.

Comment: Is the request logic run on the main thread, or inside an actor? Do you think you could you make a minimal repeater and open a ticket over at https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues ?